# Oracle , como funciona o parametro no_proxy_domains do UTL_HTTP.set_proxy

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Na *package* **UTL_HTTP** , temos o método **set_proxy** nele um parâmetro ***no_proxy_domains*** , como este funciona.

Em resumo quero fazer um request de uma URL sem precisar de autenticação.

Comment: O parâmetro no_proxy_domais apenas define quais dominíos não passarão pela configuração de proxy definida no outro parâmetro, proxy

Comment: @Artur Trapp , Por "domínios" devo entender os IPs internos ou externos ?